# Mysql slow perfomance on big table

Tags: mysql, performance

I have following table with millions rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `points` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DateNumber` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `FPTKeyId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `index3` (`FPTKeyId`,`DateNumber`) USING HASH
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16755134 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

As you can see i have created indexes. I donnt know am i do it right may be not.
The problem is queries execute super slow.

Let's take a simple query

```
SELECT fptkeyid, count FROM points group by fptkeyid
```

I cannt get result because query aborting by timeout(10 min). What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Notice: a `PRIMARY KEY` is always unique by default, so the `UNIQUE KEY (id)` is very probably unnecessary.

Comment: I searched for `mysql group by not using index`, and found this nice, long read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: Please add basic information so we can answer the question. Show some example rows, an explain of the query, an general idea of the hardware and some measurements you made before posting. That way you get more concrete answers which are suited to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

Beware MySQL's stupid behaviour: `GROUP BY`ing implicitly executes `ORDER BY`.

To prevent this, explicitely add `ORDER BY NULL`, which prevents unnecessary ordering.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html says:

> If you use GROUP BY, output rows are sorted according to the GROUP BY
>   columns as if you had an ORDER BY for the same columns. To avoid the
>   overhead of sorting that GROUP BY produces, add ORDER BY NULL:

```
SELECT a, COUNT(b) FROM test_table GROUP BY a ORDER BY NULL;
```

## +

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html says:

> The most important preconditions for using indexes for GROUP BY are
>   that all GROUP BY columns reference attributes from the same index,
>   and that the index stores its keys in order (for example, this is a
>   **BTREE** index and not a **HASH** index).

Comment: @Neir0 Well, if you have many many millions of rows, mysql have to go through each and every one of them when you don't have any where clause in the query. That takes time. You might need to have a summary table, storing these aggregates if you need to frequently run queries such as this one.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally start with your `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.  You have set it to *increase by `16,755,134` for each new record*.  Your field value is set to `INT UNSIGNED` which means that the range of values is `0 to 4,294,967,295` (or almost 4.3 billion).  This means that you would have *only `256` values* before the field goes beyond the data type limits thereby compromising the purpose of the `PRIMARY KEY INDEX`.

You could changed the data type to `BIGINT UNSIGNED` and you would have a value range of `0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615` (or slightly more then 18.4 quintillion) which would allow you to have *up to `1,100,960,700,983` (or slightly more then 1.1 trillion) unique values* with this `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.

I would first ask if you really need to have your `AUTO_INCREMENT` value set to such a large number and if not then I would *suggest changing that to 1* (or at least some lower number) as storing the field values as `INT` vs `BIGINT` will save considerable disk space within larger tables such as this.  Either way, you should get a more stable `PRIMARY KEY INDEX` which should help improve queries.

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not make sense:

```
SELECT fptkeyid, count FROM points group by fptkeyid
```

You group by fptkeyid so count is not useful here. There should be an aggregate function. Not a count field. Next that that count is also a MySQL function which makes it not very useful / advisable to use the same name for a field.

Don't you need something like:

```
SELECT fptkeyid, SUM(`count`) FROM points group by fptkeyid
```

If not please explain what result you expect from the query.

Created a database with test data, half a million records, to see if I can find something equal to your issue. This is what the explain tells me:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  points  index   NULL    index3  10  NULL    433756
```

And on the SUM query:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  points  index   NULL    index3  10  NULL    491781
```

Both queries are done on a laptop (macbook air) within a second, nothing takes long. Inserting though took some time, few minutes to get half a million records. But retrieving and calculating does not.

We need more to answer your question totally complete. Maybe the configuration of the database is wrong, for example almost no memory allocated?

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is your server bandwidth. Having a million rows would probably need at least high megabyte bandwidths.

Comment: im executing query on my local machine